# How to mock so that `from x import *` works

Tags: python, mocking, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a Mock of matplotlib so that I can compile my docs using ReadTheDocs, but have run into a problem.

In my code, I import matplotlib using `from matplotlib.pyplot import *`.

I am using the following code for my Mocks (as suggested by the [ReadTheDocs FAQ](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html)):

```
class Mock(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Mock()

    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        if name in ('__file__', '__path__'):
            return '/dev/null'
        elif name[0] == name[0].upper():
            return type(name, (), {})
        else:
            return Mock()

MOCK_MODULES = ['numpy', 'scipy', 'matplotlib', 'matplotlib.pyplot']
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = Mock()
```

However, when running `from matplotlib.pyplot import *` I get an error saying that `TypeError: 'type' object does not support indexing`.

Is there a way that I can change my Mock so that it allows me to import matplotlib using the `from x import *` style? I don't need any particular functions to be made available, I just need it to be able to be imported so that ReadTheDocs can import the code properly.

Comment: Side note: Don't roll your own general-purpose mock. Use the excellent `mock` library, in 3.3. it's even in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I found that importing the `mock` library and then using the `mock.Mock` class instead of the one suggested by ReadTheDocs made it all work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of importing via `*` you need to define the `__all__` list in the module. The same goes with your class: just add the `__all__` attribute to the class and it should work fine:

```
class Mock(object):
    __all__ = []
```

Comment: ReadTheDocs FAQ is suggesting MagicMock:

    from unittest.mock import MagicMock
    
    class Mock(MagicMock):
        __all__ = []
        @classmethod
        def __getattr__(cls, name):
                return Mock()
    
    MOCK_MODULES = ['tkinter', 'tkinter.ttk']
    sys.modules.update((mod_name, Mock()) for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES)

But it doesn't work for tkinter.ttk ...